# Resharper disable IntelliSense for SerializePrivateVariables

Tags: unity-game-engine, resharper, intellisense

After updating the Unity3d to version 2017, I encountered a very unpleasant problem.
Which makes me very upset...

When I write "var" and press "spacebar" IntelliSense (resharper Code Completion) autoreplace this to "SerializePrivateVariables"

Is it possible to disable this autoreplacement? With out disable all IntelliSense.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes i use Visual Studio